# Salesforce OAuth - Bad Response Error

Tags: c#, salesforce

I downloaded the Salesforce [.Net sample](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET) for OAuth functionality testing.

My Developer account configuration is,

[image]

My Webconfig,
[image]

I get the Auth token without an issue and it hits the Callback controller.

But when it executes,

```
await auth.WebServerAsync(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret, _callbackUrl, code, _tokenRequestEndpointUrl);
```

Code to get the Accesstoken I get an error, (this happens because it cannot parse the response which is very strange.)

```
  <Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>Salesforce.Common.ForceAuthException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at Salesforce.Common.AuthenticationClient.<WebServerAsync>d__28.MoveNext() in C:\Users\DhanukaS.INFRONT\Desktop\SFNew\SFNew\src\CommonLibrariesForNET\AuthenticationClient.cs:line 139 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() at WebServerOAuthFlow.Web.Controllers.CallbackController.<Get>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Users\DhanukaS.INFRONT\Desktop\SFNew\SFNew\samples\WebServerOAuthFlow\WebServerOAuthFlow.Web\Controllers\CallbackController.cs:line 23 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

Then I debugged "WebServerAsync" code and found that I am getting a 400 Bad Request.

What I have posted was

```
grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrCKIMxh0dN7HmIE24cMYzog1sD.wPQIOTmpDkaoh5SYOcvKQ7ckwl7pw9H3KWQHHhHwR.gv&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxx79169&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A6054%2Fapi%2Fcallback&code=aPrxqJ8A8kLOza.c1DZ2Ye1YZ09ybmbRd8xxxxxxxxxxxx9qmE.LGHsyUJA2OKC25.qD.g%3D%3D
```

In the response it says,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
<title>Stronger security is required</title>
<style>
@font-face{
    font-family:'SalesforceSansLight';src:url('https://www.salesforce.com/system/shared/common/assets/fonts/SalesforceSans/SalesforceSans-Light.eot');
    src:url(..........'
```

I tried similar thing with another app, same result. Do I have to do any configuration from Salesforce account. Suprising why this basic scenario is not working?

Referring to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm), is HTTPS mandatory even for localhost?